# Sql server error 916 when using a trigger that selects data in other database (outside sql server only)

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Hy friends,

I'm going mad with this error below:

The server principal "LOGINNAME" is not able to access the database "DATABASENAME" udner the current security context. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916).

This begins to occurs after I created a trigger in database X that selects data on database Y. I had mapped de login with datareader and datawriter access to the database Y, DBO schema but the error persists. The most strange fact is, when I update the triggered table via SQL Management Studio with the same login, the error doesn't occurs. It only occurs via front-end application (VFP9 in case). Then only way to make it Works is giving Sysadmin access...

Please, anyone can help me to solve this mistery ?

Thanks,

Tinoco

Comment: Triggers are executed in the context of the user running the outer query and that user probably doesn't have permission on the other database. Also, this sounds like a huge performance issue, triggers should be very simple and fast.

Comment: Thanks for replyig DavidG, but the user that is running the outer query is the same user. the trigger is very simple, I only verify the existence of the data in the database Y to return error if it doesn't. This other database is in the same sql server.